# How does this recursive binary search work? For finding the kth smallest node in a bst

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-search-tree

I saw this binary search/dps solution the other day, and im having difficulty understanding how this works.

```
def kthSmallest(self, root, k):  # Binary Search - DPS
    def countNodes(node):
        if not node:
            return 0
        return 1 + countNodes(node.left) + countNodes(node.right)

    count = countNodes(root.left)
    if k <= count:
        return self.kthSmallest(root.left, k)
    elif k > count + 1:
        return self.kthSmallest(root.right, k - 1 - count)
    return root.val
```

Comment: The idea is to skip over the first `k-1` nodes (as if though doing an inorder traversal of the tree), and return the next node's value.  If the left subtree has less than `k-1` nodes, where does that next node have to be?  If the left subtree has more than `k-1` nodes, where does that next node have to be?  If the left subtree has *exactly* `k-1` nodes, where does that next node have to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first look at the `countNodes` function that is defined inside `kthSmallest`: It counts the number of nodes of the BST rooted at `root` by recursively aggregating the number of nodes of the BST rooted at `node.left` and `node.right`. The base case is that there is no Node, in which case `countNodes` returns 0.

The logic behind `kthSmallest` hinges on the property of BSTs that the key of a given node is larger than all the nodes in the subtree rooted at its left child and that it is smaller than all the nodes in the subtree rooted at its right child. The invariant that is maintained throughout the recursive calls is that the kth smallest node is contained in the subtree rooted at `root`: At the first call, `root` is the root of the BST, so this condition is true. The algorithm then counts the number of nodes in the left subtree of `root`. By the BST property, this is the number of nodes smaller than `root`. If this number is larger or equal to `k`, the kth smallest node must be in the left subtree, so the algorithm recurses into the left subtree. If the number + 1 is smaller than `k`, the sought after node must be in the right subtree, so the algorithm recurses there (+1 is added because the node itself is counted). This recursion needs to adjust `k` to `k-1-count` since `count + 1` is the number of nodes smaller then the right child of `root`. Finally, if `k=count + 1` the current `node` is the kth-smallest node (since its left subtree has `k-1` nodes) and the algorithm returns the value of the node.

Here is an example:
Let's say we have the following BST and are looking for the 3rd smallest node:

```
  3.
 /  \
1    5
/\  / \
   4  6
   /\ /\
       8
       /\
```

We first call `kthSmallest` on the root (3), so `count` is 1 and since `k = 3 > count + 1`, the algorithm recurses into the right subtree with the new adjusted `k=3-1-1=1`:

```
  5
 / \
4  6
/\ /\
    8
```

Now `count` is 1 and since `k=1 <= 1`, the algorithm recurses into the left subtree:

```
4
/\
```

Now `count` is 0 so `k = count + 1` and the algorithm returns `4`, which is the 3rd smallest node in the sequence `1 3 4 5 6 8`.